# Prevent Overlapping Sounds with use-sound / howler

Tags: javascript, reactjs, audio, howler.js, usesound

I am transitioning to `use-sound` as my audio player right now, but I have a problem when having multiple components on the same page. My sounds are a bit longer than simple beeps, so the problem is that sounds will be overlapping if the user clicks on multiple components that trigger `useSound`.

The `interrupt` flag that useSound provides is very useful when using sprites or having multiple sounds in *one* component, but I am using multiple components, so the instances won't affect each other.

Here is my basic component:

```js
import useSound from 'use-sound';

const Button = ({soundPath}) => {
  const [play] = useSound(soundPath, { interrupt: true });

  return <button onClick={play}>Boop!</button>;
};
```

and I am using it like so:

```js
<div>
   <Button soundPath="https://...audio1.mp3" />
   <Button soundPath="https://...audio2.mp3" />
   <Button soundPath="https://...audio3.mp3" />
</div>
```

I had this problem before when using a different audio player, and I used to solve it by finding all html `<audio>` tags and pausing them, like so:

```
 document.addEventListener(
            "play",
            function (e) {
              var audios = document.getElementsByTagName("audio");
              for (var i = 0, len = audios.length; i < len; i++) {
                if (audios[i] != e.target) {
                  audios[i].pause();
                  audios[i].currentTime = 0;
                }
              }
            },
            true
          );
```

Not the most elegant solution, but it worked. This doesn't seem to work with `use-sound` and I am not sure why? It seems like it does not inject `<audio>` tags into the DOM.

Any ideas on how I could solve this?

Comment: Put all the sprites in a single context and share them to individual components

Comment: thanks, but that's not going to work for my use case, unfortunately. the components will have to be their own isolated components with their own context :(

Comment: @antonwilhelm Could you provide the exact limitations of your current use case and possibly a minimal reproduction of your use case, please. Also, would you be able to pass a mutex to each component?

Comment: If not, would a global mutex be possible in your use case?

Comment: thanks for your answer. Yeah, I guess that would be possible, but I think a simple loop through the DOM would also be just fine, if possible.

Comment: @antonwilhelm I thought your issue was that `useSound` didn't inject `<audio>` tags so you wouldn't be able to loop through the DOM for them?

Comment: Why don't use useRef hook to keep track of the currently playing sound, and stop it before playing a new sound?

Comment: @antonwilhelm It would really help if we had a minimal reproducible example of your issue. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did:

```
import {
  useState,
  useEffect,
} from "react"

import useSound from "use-sound";

const Button = ({
  id,
  soundPath,
  currentPlayButton,
  setCurrentPlayButton,
}) => {

  const [play, { stop }] = useSound(soundPath, {
    interrupt: true,  });

  const handleClick = () => {
    play();
    setCurrentPlayButton(id);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    if (id !== currentPlayButton) {
      stop();
    }
  }, [currentPlayButton, id]);

  return <button onClick={handleClick}>Boop!</button>;
};

const AllButtons = () => {
  const [currentPlayButton, setCurrentPlayButton] = useState(0)

  return (
    <>
      <Button
        id={1}
        currentPlayButton={currentPlayButton}
        soundPath="https://...audio1.mp3"
        setCurrentPlayButton={setCurrentPlayButton}
      />
      <Button
        id={2}
        currentPlayButton={currentPlayButton}
        soundPath="https://...audio1.mp3"
        setCurrentPlayButton={setCurrentPlayButton}
      />
    </>
  );
};

export default AllButtons;
```

1. The `id` prop is used to differentiate one button from another.
2. The `currentPlayButton` prop is used to keep track of which button is currently clicked.
3. The `setCurrentPlayButton` prop is a function used to change the value of `currentPlayButton`.
4. The `useEffect` inside the `<Button/>` component is used to ensure that only one button can be played at a time.

Answer (score 0):

## React Context for State and a Callback With a `useSound` Wrapper

We can utilize React's Context API to create a context that stores the last sound to be played and provides a callback that stops the last sound, starts the new sound, and stores it. Then we can make a hook that wraps `useSound` and its `play` function to interact with our context.

[View this example live at CodeSandbox.](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-context-single-audio-usesound-x3hovg?file=/src/hooks/useSound.js)

```
// src/App.js
import { SoundProvider } from "./components/SoundProvider.js";
import { SoundButton } from "./components/SoundButton.js";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <SoundProvider>
      <SoundButton src="/sounds/water-hose-gun.mp3">
        <span role="img" aria-label="Water gun">
          
        </span>
      </SoundButton>
      <SoundButton src="/sounds/cool-jazz.mp3">
        <span role="img" aria-label="Trumpet">
          
        </span>
      </SoundButton>
      <SoundButton src="/sounds/speaking.mp3">
        <span role="img" aria-label="Person speaking">
          ️
        </span>
      </SoundButton>
      <SoundButton src="/sounds/car-park-explosion.mp3">
        <span role="img" aria-label="Explosion">
          
        </span>
      </SoundButton>
    </SoundProvider>
  );
}
```

With this method, you can nest the `<SoundButton>` in as many other components as you want and in different sections of your app, and it will still be able to interact with the nearest `<SoundProvider>`.

```
// src/contexts/sound.js
import { createContext } from "react";
export const SoundContext = createContext(null);
```

```
// src/components/SoundProvider
import { useCallback, useState } from "react";
import { SoundContext } from "../contexts/sound";

export function SoundProvider(props) {
  const [sound, setSound] = useState(null);

  const playSound = useCallback(
    (newSound, ...args) => {
      sound?.[1].stop();
      setSound(newSound);
      newSound[0](...args);
    },
    [sound]
  );

  return <SoundContext.Provider {...props} value={{ sound, playSound }} />;
}
```

```
// src/hooks/useSound.js
import { useContext } from "react";
import { SoundContext } from "../contexts/sound";
import useSound from "use-sound";

function useSoundWrapper(src, hookOptions) {
  const sound = useSound(src, hookOptions);
  const { playSound } = useContext(SoundContext);
  return [(...args) => playSound(sound, ...args), sound[1]];
}
export { useSoundWrapper as useSound };
```

This wrapper implementation makes using this solution no different than using the original `useSound`. As you can see below, nothing really changes for the `<SoundButton>` besides the import.

```
// src/components/SoundButton.js
import { useSound } from "../hooks/useSound.js";

export function SoundButton({ src, ...props }) {
  const [play] = useSound(src, { interrupt: true });
  return <button onClick={play} {...props} />;
}
```